# How can I find and replace in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to change the server paths that were stored in my database (Wordpress), so I am searching for the string "/home/".  Is there some kind of command such as `str_replace($search, $replace, $subject)` equivalent in SQL?

**Edit:** What if I don't know what the field name is? Well, I do, but there is more than one field name. I was just hoping for a more "global" solution like in Notepad++ where I can just find all and replace all, but it seems I can only update a certain field / table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET server_path = REPLACE(server_path,'/home/','/new_home/');
```

[Link to documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html).

Edit:
If you need to update multiple fields you can string them along—with commas in between—in that same `UPDATE` statement, e.g.:

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET mycol1 = REPLACE(mycol1,'/home/','/new_home/'), 
       mycol2 = REPLACE(mycol2,'/home/','/new_home/');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update [table_name] set [field_name] = replace([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');
```